# Unexpected result with regular expressions in Android

Tags: android, regex

I want to validate text inputs with a helper class. I started with a method to prove for a single name with upper case at the beginning and max length of 20 characters:

```
package xyz.helper;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public abstract class InputValidator {  
    public static boolean checkSingleName(String string) {  
        return Pattern.matches("^[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜ]{1}[a-zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûü]{1,19}", string); 
    }
}
```

When I test in the Activity for example with "Hello", I get back FALSE and the error message. Is my regular expression wrong?

```
// Check User entries
private boolean checkEntries() {
    boolean validEntry = InputValidator.checkSingleName(title.toString());
        if (!validEntry) {
            title.setError(getString(R.string.error_occasion));
            return false;    
        }
        return true;    
}
```

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you've built the sentence is not right currently. I'd try this way:

```
return Pattern.compile("^[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜ]{1}[a-zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûü]{1,19}").matcher("Hello").matches()
```

Comment: this also doesn't work. The expression works fine in the regex tool, though

Comment: Yes, that's strange as I've also tested it within several regex tools and all retrieves `true`. Could you, just in case, try without the special characters?

Comment: I tried it with: "^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,19}", but still false

Comment: Try by: `^[A-Z][a-z]{1,19}.*`

Answer (score 0):

Often, in questions like this, it is what you are NOT showing that is the problem.

Demonstration of a working Java implementation of your regex (see http://ideone.com/nFPcic):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      if(checkSingleName("Hello")) {
        System.out.println("Yes that is valid");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("No that is not valid");
      }// your code goes here
    }
    public static boolean checkSingleName(String string) {  
        return Pattern.matches("^[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜ]{1}[a-zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûü]{1,19}", string); 
    }
}
```

This prints out "Yes that is valid" with `"Hello"` as the input string. When I add a digit to the name, it prints "Not that is not valid". As expected.

If you are getting a different result, it is because of something you are not showing. **Could it be there is a carriage return, space or tab at the start/end of the string you are testing?**

Incidentally, you really don't need the `{1}` after the initial capital letter; and your regex is terribly restrictive. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lowercase_proper_names_or_pseudonyms , or even better, http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ - thought provoking and at times hilarious.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't test the string. The problem was here:     checkSingleName(title.toString()); It has to be title.getText().toString().

Comment: @Cellist - and to be able to know that, I would have to know your definition of `title` which was not in the code you shared... :-) "It is what you are NOT showing that is the problem". I rest my case.